# json_object_iterator.h not Found

Tags: c

I am trying to parse JSON object from C program. but i got following error.

my c program contains `json/json.h` header file. this header file is causing below error. May I need to install anything. I saw few posts related to it but not helped me to figure out the problem.

here is the Error I got while Compiling my program.

```
**/usr/local/include/json/json.h:27:34: fatal error: json_object_iterator.h: No such file or directory**
**compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [cconnect.o] Error 1**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**14.04**

You need to install the following -dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-c-dev
```

---

**Update (12.04)**

Since `libjson-c-dev` is only available for 14.04, you have to install the corresponding debian packages by hand (which is not recommended).

Download the following deb packages:

- [libjson-c-dev_0.11-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson-c-dev_0.11-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb)
- [libjson-c2_0.11-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson-c2_0.11-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb)

Open a Terminal and go to the folder where you saved the two deb files and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i libjson*.deb
```

Now you have `/usr/include/json-c/json_object_iterator.h` installed on your system.

Note that installing packages this way only works in that case because the dependencies are still satisfied on 12.04 (`libc6 >= 2.14`).

Comment: #apt-get install libjson-c-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjson-c-dev

Comment: i got error : unable to locate the package..

Comment: It's available for 14.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libjson-c-dev. Are you running 12.04?

Comment: yes, i am using 12.04, 64 bit Ubuntu.. How can i install it ??

Comment: @VenkateshMacha I've updated my answer with a way to install the missing header in 12.04. (I was logged out during the edit, that's why the edit is owned by Community...)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer Sylvain Pineau, I Installed JSON-C from Source code [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/json-c_releases/releases/json-c-0.12.tar.gz) and it is working fine..